# Regex for Multiple Deny Selection

Tags: regex

I am new to the regex world. I have been using regex for a while but today I found a problem I couldn't resolve. I searched the forum but got no luck.

I have to do like a negative match. I have to match tables like `EOS.1` and `EOS.2` but there are up to `EOS.9000` tables. They are not consecutive, I have to leave behind some tables like `90`, `91`, `2293`, `3750`, etc.

I tried this pattern:

```
 EOS\.(?!91|90|2300|2504|3747|3750|100|3788|2303|2304|2293)
```

However, it only matches the `EOS.` part, not the numbers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter out some numbers from the 1-9000 range?

Comment: No, I have to match every patern of EOS.(Number) that is not the ones mention. But they are not in consecutive order, for expample you have EOS.0 but then jumps to EOS.9 and the to 11. So I thought that given that i cannot do a multiple match because they are thousands of tables i thought to match everything except the one i dont need

Comment: I just want to point out, I found while messing with this that if you have, say EOS.9000, it will not be matched because of the 90. Not sure if you were aware.

Comment: @Physik: Yes, because no word boundary was used after the `90`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the below regex:

```
\bEOS\.(?!(91|90|2300|2504|3747|3750|100|3788|2303|2304|2293)\b)(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|[1-8][0-9]{3}|9000)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sG3mR1/1)

This regex matches full word `EOS` followed by a literal `.` and numbers from 1 up to 9000, excluding those in the negative lookahead.

Your `EOS\.(?!91|90|2300|2504|3747|3750|100|3788|2303|2304|2293)` regex matches only `EOS.` part because look-aheads do not consume characters, only check their presence or absence.

Comment: Excelent! It works like a charm, I didnt know that the negative looks-ahead only check presence. Thank you very much

Comment: You can read more about [look-arounds on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).